# как переделать запрос с insert into на update

Tags: php, sql

Подскажите, как переписать этот запрос на update? в  were id=1

конкретно этот

```
// $sql = "INSERT INTO minutes_for_graf ( block_time, block_reward, difficulty24, nethash, exchange_rate ) VALUES ('".($row['Decred']['block_time'])."','".($row['Decred']['block_reward'])."','".($row['Decred']['difficulty24'])."','".($row['Decred']['nethash'])."','".($row['Decred']['exchange_rate'])."')";
```

вся функция

```
<?php
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root","forgraf");
$filename = "asic.json";

$data = file_get_contents($filename);
$array = json_decode($data, true);
foreach($array as $row){


// $sql = "INSERT INTO minutes_for_graf ( block_time, block_reward, difficulty24, nethash, exchange_rate ) VALUES ('".($row['Decred']['block_time'])."','".($row['Decred']['block_reward'])."','".($row['Decred']['difficulty24'])."','".($row['Decred']['nethash'])."','".($row['Decred']['exchange_rate'])."')";

    
    mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
    var_dump($row);    
}
?>
```

Comment: что у вас не получилось? `update minutes_for_graf set a=b, c=d where id=1`

Comment: @splash58 ```$sql = "UPDATE minutes_for_graf SET block_time = $row['Decred']['block_time']    WHERE id=1 ";``` вот так?

Comment: я не разбирался с данными. но как-то так

Comment: жаль, но строка не работает(

Comment: что означает "не работает"? ошибка? нет id?

Comment: @splash58 Если написать вот так ````$sql = "UPDATE minutes_for_graf SET exchange_rate = '({$row['Decred']['exchange_rate']})'    WHERE id=1 ";```` то данные не обновляются в базе

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть встроенные функции для конкатенации массива,например [implode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php), но при этом нужно соблюсти порядок ключей и значений при использование INSERT, для этого лучше использовать INSERT SET, а не VALUE, ибо при огромном количестве атрибутов, сложно поддерживать порядок правильного ввода.

В место
`INSERT INTO table (a, b, c) VALUES (1,2,3)`

Что-то типа:

`INSERT INTO table SET a=1, b=2, c=3`

Если взять Ваш пример за основу, то:

`$sql = "INSERT INTO minutes_for_graf ( block_time, block_reward, difficulty24, nethash, exchange_rate ) VALUES ('".($row['Decred']['block_time'])."','".($row['Decred']['block_reward'])."','".($row['Decred']['difficulty24'])."','".($row['Decred']['nethash'])."','".($row['Decred']['exchange_rate'])."')";`

Можно немного модернизировать под следующий код:

```
$row['Decred'] = [
        'block_time' => '2',
        'difficulty24' => '4'
    ];

if (array_key_exists('Decred', $row)) {
    $rowDecredData = $row['Decred'];

$changedData = array_reduce(array_keys($rowDecredData), function($carryData, $attrName) use($rowDecredData) {
        return array_merge($carryData, ["$attrName=\"$rowDecredData[$attrName]\""]);
    }, []);

$concatenatedToStringData = implode(', ', $changedData);

$insertIntoQuerySql = <<<SQL
    INSERT INTO minutes_for_graf SET $concatenatedToStringData
SQL;
}
```

Запрос ввода будет выглядеть следующим образом `INSERT INTO minutes_for_graf SET block_time="2", difficulty24="4"`.

Следовательно по данной аналогии остается сделать небольшие изменения в теле запроса:
`UPDATE minutes_for_graf SET block_time="2", difficulty24="4" WHERE id=1`